# Entity Framework - Update Model from Database - New Column

Tags: entity-framework, updatemodel

What is the process I should follow to update my entity framework model when I have simply added a new column to a table in the database?   The process that I have followed was to right click within the edmx file and choose "Update Model from Database".  Now I can see the new field against the table definition in the Store.  But when I look at the table mapping for the entity itself I see that my new column shows up but is not mapped to a property on the entity.  Surely I don't have to manually add a property to the entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've realised this was not really a problem - the only problem was my understanding of what was happening.  The new column I was referring to was actually a foreign key relationship with another table and therefore it did show up as a navigation property .  When I go and add a column to my table that is not a foreign key it shows up as expected when using "Update Model from Database".